# 'global' in python can reference to undefined variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scope, global

While I was learning LEGB scope rule of python, I wanted a deeper understanding of how global works in python. It seems that even if I refer to an undefined variable(Which is also not in builtins), The code doesn't give me an error. Please help me figure out what actually is happening.

```
def hey():
    x = 1
    def hey2():
        global ew #ew not defined in the module
        x = 2
        print(x)
    hey2()
    print(x)
hey()

OUTPUT: 2
        1
```

Comment: read all these answers and you'll have a deeper understanding of how global works, including your current concern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: Since you are not using the variable, nothing is actually happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `global` is used to **create or update a global variable locally**

```
def hey():
    x = 1
    def hey2():
        global ew #reference to create or update a global variable named ew
        ew=2 # if you comment this global variable will not be created 
        x = 2
        #print(x)
    hey2()
    #print(x)
print '\t ------Before function call-----'
print globals()
hey()

print '\n'
print '\t -----After function call------ '
print globals()
```

`globals()` will give you a dictionary of all objects the global scope contains

you can see in the second dictionary `ew` is present, which was not present in the first dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) can apply to a name that is not bound (an undefined variable) or even never used. It doesn't create the name, but informs the compiler that this name should be looked up only in a global scope, not in the local scope. The difference shows up in the compiled code as distinct operations:

```
>>> def foo():
...   global g
...   l = 1
...   g = 2
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (l)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (g)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

We see that `STORE_FAST` was used for a local variable, while `STORE_GLOBAL` was used for the global variable. There isn't any output for the `global` statement itself; it only changed how references to `g` operate.

Answer (score -1):

Simple example  of global variabl in two functions
    def hey():
        global x
        x = 1
        print x
    hey() # prints 1
    def hey2():
        global x
        x += 2
        print x
    hey2() #prints 3